# Deploy Web Service using Jboss 6

Tags: web-services, jboss, netbeans-7, jboss6.x

I create a web service using net beans 7.1 and Jboss.

i am following the steps of this tutorial:

```
http://campuscurico.utalca.cl/~pabrojas/?page_id=192
```

But when i deploy the project with glassfish i go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/webServiceName?WSDL
```

And it show me the wsdl.

But when i deploy the project with Jboss 6.1 Final, and i go to the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/webServiceName?WSDL
```

The page show me `Estado HTTP 404 - /`

but when i go to the:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/
```

Show me the index jsp page

What is my problem, why i can't deploy the project with jboss?

Who can help me?.

Thanks

I do not if i need configure my web.xml

I have this web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the generated WSDL in your JBOSS. You can find it in your JBOSS Home directory:
JBOSS6/standalone/data/wsdl...
In the WSDL the url to your wsdl is specified in the soap:address tag.
If no wsdl is stored in your jboss you have to share some more information about your web service files.